# Accommodating Dynamic Hierarchies in a Data Warehouse Model

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I am building a data warehouse for the company's (which I am working for) core ERP application, for a particular client.

Most of the data in the source database, which is related to hierarchies in the data warehouse are in columns as shown below:[image: Source ProductDescription table]

But traditionally the model to store dimension data according to my knowledge is as:[image: data warehouse DimProduct table]

I could pivot the data and fit them in the model shown above. But the issue comes when a user introduces a new hierarchy value. Say for instance the user in the future decides to define a new level called **Product Sub Category**. Then my entire data warehouse model will collapse without a way to accommodate the new hierarchy level defined.

Do let me know a way to overcome this situation.

I hope my answer is clear enough. Just let me know if further details are needed.

Answer (score 2):

Well, nothing should collapse -- the ETL should extract and load the data as always.

Here are a few options to consider:

1. Simply add one more column for the new hierarchy to the `dimProduct`.
2. Try using **[hierarchy helper table](http://www.kimballgroup.com/html/designtipsPDF/DesignTips2004/KimballDT62Alternative.pdf)**.
3. Consider adding **[path string attribute](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2004/08/05/hierarchical_sql.html?page=1)** to the `dimProduct`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will go through the options you have proposed. For options 2 and 3 I will need to go through the links provided to get a full understanding. Adding a column will require configuration from our side, ya? That is we will simply need to convince the customer about our involvement.